# Binary multiple logistic regression with 1 categorical and 2 other predictor variable

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-significance, categorical-data, biostatistics

I have a binary logistic regression in which I have the following predictors: 1 continuous variable watering, 1 indicator variable or categorical variable colour (black, blue, red) and 1 predictor which i do not know if its a factor or continuous (in this one, I have fertilizer from 0 to 4.5 gm and repeated 10 time) with a total n=120. My y=0 if success, 1 if fail. What is the model that I can use to estimate the probability of success given both the treatment and colour?